# what is the functionality of "@jsx react.dom" adding in top of every file?

Tags: reactjs

what is the functionality of:

```
 /** @jsx React.DOM */
```

I have seen this line is added on top of so many files in my current project but I am very confused why its added. :(

Comment: It is no longer needed as of React 0.12. The explanation for why it was ever needed is [on Github here](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/841).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since React v0.12, there's no more `/** @jsx React.DOM */`, [see here](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/10/28/react-v0.12.html#jsx-changes).

They call it ["The @jsx Pragma"](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/10/16/react-v0.12-rc1.html#the-jsx-pragma-is-gone). It was used to allow you to specific how the output of the React Transformer should look.

So, back in the days, when compiling JSX expressions to JavaScript, they defaulted to `React.createElement()` calls. But you could modify this behavior with the beginning `/** @jsx React.DOM */` comment. The idea was to make the transform more generic and allow you to specific how the output should look.

Not anymore. The React team shares in their release v0.12 notes:

> We have wanted to do this since before we even open sourced React. No more `/** @jsx React.DOM */`!. The React specific JSX transform assumes you have React in scope (which had to be true before anyway).

Comment: Thank you @kaloyan this was really very helpful. I was searching for the same short and simple explanation.